# Sails.js special character routes

Tags: node.js, sails.js, special-characters

If I do the following request :

```
http://localhost:1337/search/###
```

The request won't be routed to my `searchBySlug` method of the `SearchController` because of the #.

How can I do to have that url routed to the correct method?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `http://localhost:1337/search/%23%23%23` and parse that URL encoded to string?

To decode use `decodeURIComponent('%23%23%23')` will result `###`